# How can I sort time dimensions in SSAS cubes? Poor sort is causing issues with ParallelPeriod()

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I have an old cube built in SSAS. We break revenue down into a time dimension like so:

| fiscal week | Date | Revenue | Prior Year Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 2020-12-31 | $5000 | ???? |
| 49 | 2020-12-03 | $1000 | $200 (should be $100) |
| 50 | 2020-12-10 | $2000 | $300 |
| 51 | 2020-12-17 | $3000 | $400 |
| 52 | 2020-12-24 | $4000 | $500 |

As you can see, the 53rd fiscal week is not displaying in the proper sort order.

This is becoming a problem due for a dimension we use, "Prior Year, Week". This attempts to grab the revenue from the same fiscal week instead of the previous year. It accomplishes this by calling `ParallelPeriod([FiscalWeek], 52), [Measures].[Revenue])`.

What I believe is happening is that because week 53 is at the beginning of the month, `ParallelPeriod` is counting it as one of the intervals it skips. This results in the Prior Year column showing fiscal week 50 when it should be 51, 51 when it should be 52, etc.

Is there a way to sort those dates? I've tried the obvious `KeyColumn`stuff and examined the source views, and nothing seems like it should be causing this poor sort.

Thanks in advance -- I don't know much about this stuff and am sort of being tossed into the deep end here.

EDIT:

I've made some progress here but still having issues. It appears that every year with 53 fiscal weeks would have this problem -- week 53 is sorted improperly.

The time dimension breaks down like this:

- Year
- Quarter
- Month
- Week Number
- Bill Date

The bill dates are sorted in order, but for some reason, the weeks in the Browser look like this:

- 53
- 1
- 2
- 3
- ...
- 52. 

It appears that the Week Number attribute is the one that's off. The `OrderBy` property is set to `AttributeKey` and the `OrderByAttribute` property is set to `Bill Date attribute`. However, viewing just the pubdates reveals that they are properly sorted.

EDIT:

After setting the `OrderBy` to `Key` as suggested by the response below, it appears that some of the month hierarchies are out of order. For instance, certain months are containing weeks that don't belong. For example:

```
* Sep
  * 35
    * 2020-08-27
  * 36
    * 2020-09-03
  * 37
    * 2020-09-10
  * 38
    * 2020-09-17
  * 39
    * 2020-09-24
```

Here's the XML for the month attribute:

```xml
<Attribute>
                    <ID>Month attribute</ID>
                    <Name>Month attribute</Name>
                    <Type>Months</Type>
                    <EstimatedCount>48</EstimatedCount>
                    <KeyColumns>
                        <KeyColumn>
                            <DataType>WChar</DataType>
                            <Source xsi:type="ColumnBinding">
                                <TableID>dbo_dim_time</TableID>
                                <ColumnID>fiscalmonth</ColumnID>
                            </Source>
                        </KeyColumn>
                    </KeyColumns>
                    <NameColumn>
                        <DataType>WChar</DataType>
                        <Source xsi:type="ColumnBinding">
                            <TableID>dbo_dim_time</TableID>
                            <ColumnID>fiscalmonth</ColumnID>
                        </Source>
                    </NameColumn>
                    <AttributeRelationships>
                        <AttributeRelationship>
                            <AttributeID>Pubdate attribute</AttributeID>
                            <Name>Pubdate attribute</Name>
                        </AttributeRelationship>
                    </AttributeRelationships>
                    <OrderBy>AttributeKey</OrderBy>
                    <OrderByAttributeID>Pubdate attribute</OrderByAttributeID>
                    <MembersWithData>NonLeafDataHidden</MembersWithData>
                    <MembersWithDataCaption>(* data)</MembersWithDataCaption>
                    <AttributeHierarchyVisible>false</AttributeHierarchyVisible>
                </Attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **OrderBy** design you described referencing **Bill Date** seems overly complex for your requirements.

For the **Week Number** attribute, I would just set the **OrderBy** property to **Key**.

Comment: Do I have to process all cubes that use this dimension after making this change?

Comment: Not sure. Probably best to, to be safe.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to deal with the dates being sorted into the wrong fiscal month as described in my edit?